# Checksum not matching

Tags: elementary-website

elementary 5 checksum not matched on download. Tried download twice. Tried different apps, still same problem.

Both downloads share the same checksum when checked, only its not the one stated on elementary website.

Any help guys?

Comment: did you tried download with bt? they have magnet link on website.

Comment: hi Hasan, yeah did that too. still same checksum as others but again different to elementary website.

Comment: checksum should be...

Comment: a8c7b8c54aeb0889bb3245356ffcd95b77e9835ffb5ac56376a3b627c3e1950f

Comment: im getting this instead....    5d47af2d5ae95715188234101f6b269e03288d06827d95370e381ccfead292ed

Comment: sorry user6308 for calling you Hasan

Comment: if checksum is different in every download, then your computer may have problem, try download from other network/computer. and , are you comparing same checksum? (md5/sha1, etc)

Comment: thanks for the advice. I'll try on a different network then on a different computer. Yes I've been comparing same checksums too with SHA256. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Downloading on a different network solved the problem. Not sure what this means with regard the first network I used though.